# Удаление строк в файле csv с помощью python

Tags: python, строки, csv, удаление

У меня есть csv, в котором около 1000 строк. Мне нужно удалить все строки ниже 100 (т.е. начиная со 101). Но при этом мне нужно сохранить в исходной папке только укороченный csv.
Как это можно сделать стандартными средствами python?

Comment: С чем у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Comment: Я прочитал построчно csv, а как удалить лишние строки?

Comment: прочитайте или до 100, или все и сделайте срез

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алгоритм:

1. переименовываем исходный файл, добавляя расширение ".bkp":
2. создаём новый файл с именем исходного файла
3. в цикле читаем строки по одной из исходного файла и записываем в новый
4. когда счетчик доходит до 100 выходим из цикла

---

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = "/path/to/filename.txt"
bkp_filename = filename + ".bkp"
Path(filename).rename(bkp_filename)
fn_in = Path(bkp_filename)
fn_out = Path(filename)
N = 10

with open(fn_in) as fin, open(fn_out, "w") as fout:
    for i, line in enumerate(fin):
        if i == N:
            break
        fout.write(line)
```

---

**UPD:** для удобства можно также воспользоваться [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) (как написал в комментариях @Stanislav Volodarskiy):

```
from itertools import islice

...

with open(fn_in) as fin, open(fn_out, "w") as fout:
    for line in islice(fin, N):
        fout.write(line)
```

---

Если вы всегда работаете с маленькими кусками файлов, т.е. такими, которые гарантировано не вызовут проблем с памятью, то можно сделать чуть короче:

```
with open(fn_in) as fin, open(fn_out, "w") as fout:
    data = "".join(list(islice(fin, N)))
    fout.write(data)
```

Comment: [itertools.islice(_fin_, _100_)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) обрезает итератор без явного подсчёта.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, точно, совсем забыл о islice, спасибо!! Дополню ответ когда доберусь до компьютера)